# pandas read_csv which reads optimized data_types?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using `pandas` for analyzing medium sizes dataframes (10GB) - mostly reading, no manipulating and adding data. I read the excellent post https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/ and now I'm wondering why isn't there a `read_csv_with_optimal_dtypes` function which:

1. reads a small portion of the file
2. infers the best `dtypes` for it, as explained in the blog
3. re-reads the entire file with the optimal `dtypes` dict
4. if any downcast error occurs (as the small portion did not represent the entire data faithfully), falls back to the good old `read_csv`

I can write one myself, but it sounds so simple and useful that I'm surprised there's no such function available at the `pandas` API itself, or some 3rd party lib...

am I missing something?

Comment: One of the problems this would introduce is that you would never know what to expect when you try to manipulate the data; for example you try to set a value which cannot be represented by the inferred type of that column. However I can see the point if the objective is to have static data with minimal memory impact.

Comment: Still some problems will remain unsolved: for example for a categorical type represented by a string, how often can a value be repeated before it determines it is a level, and how big can the set of levels grow before it is rather seen as free text ?!

Comment: would take pull request to pandas with a well documented / tested function for this (which could be exposed via. kwargs to read_csv)

Comment: @MarcelZoll - categorical cardinality threshold could be configurable (e.g. unique/size < 1/4), and I guess that if you sample 10% of the data you have a pretty good estimation on the entire dataset...